# Mac OS programming and GDB: determining which thread owns a NSRecursiveLock

Tags: multithreading, macos, gdb

I am trying to debug a process with multiple threads and one of my threads is getting stuck waiting for an `NSRecursiveLock` to become available - confirmed by `GDB`. The source is written in `Objective C`.

So the big question that I am trying to answer is who is holding the lock when this happens. I looked at the call stacks for all the other threads in my process and found no clues.

This is what I see in `GDB` when I dump the state of my lock:

```
(gdb) p \*(NSRecursiveLock\*)0x4c0cf30  $24 = {  `NSObject = {`  

    isa = 0xac94a3d0  
}  

    members of NSRecursiveLock:  
       _priv = 0x0  
}
```

As you can see the above output isn't very informative.

How to figure out who is holding the lock?

Answer (score 0):

You can scan through your code and find all places where NSRecursiveLock is locked. Then in gdb `thread apply all bt` and search for some of these places.

Or alternatively you can create your custom derivative of NSRecursiveLock and overwrite lock, unlock, tryLock and lockBeforeDate methods so they will print thread id then do their job:

```
(void)lock
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSThread currentThread]);
    [super lock];
}
```

Then just use your class instead of plain NSRecursiveLock and see what thread is holding the lock.